# What does a kick-off conference really mean?

Tags: conference

I sometimes find that a conference is named with an adjective as kick-off. e.g. kick-off conference. What does it actually mean? Does it mean the final conference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the first conference in a series, or the conference that launches a project, or some other kind of *start* to something.

Definition from Google:

> noun: kick-off
>
> a start of an event or activity.
>
> synonyms: beginning, start, commencement, launch, outset, opening
>   "breakfast on the boat was a great kickoff to the weekend"

[Example](http://www.projectfires.eu/events/recent/kick-off-conference/) of usage in the context of a conference (emphasis mine):

> On September 2-4 2015, the FIRES project was officially **launched** with the **kick off meeting and conference** organized in Berlin, in the Science and Technology Park in Adlershof.